# objective c - using SWITCH with more than one expression?

Tags: objective-c, switch-statement

i want to know if its possible to use Switch but with more than one expression, and how to do that ??

(im using xcode).

thank you!

Comment: what problem is it that you are trying to solve? (to avoid a XY problem situation)

Comment: i made one switch that change the title. and another switch to change the content. but what im asking is how can i change both in the same switch.

Comment: is it possible to write something like... Switch(exp1, exp2){ and then the cases...

Comment: It's unclear what your goal is. Perhaps you should post what you have done and better explain what you want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A switch statement takes one expression and evaluates that to an integer. It is basically a jump table depending on the value. You cannot have two or more expressions there.

You can however have nested switch statements

```
switch (exp1)
{
  case x:
    switch (exp2) 
    {
     ...
    }
    break;
...
```

Comment: yes its a jump table, but looks like the switch will not solve what i wanted, but thank you for your help, appreciated.